# Tooltip follow element/spot

Tags: css, position, tooltip

I have some problem about CSS tooltip. Ok let me explain, let's say i have to picture.
One picture on left top corner and the other right top corner of browser.

When i point my mouse to left corner picture, tooltip opening right site of the picture and that's correct position but when i point my mouse to right corner picture it's still open right site of the picture and that's wrong position.

What i need is when i point my mouse to right top corner picture the tooltip automatic open at left side of the picture.

CSS can do that or better using javascript to open tooltip? Because i try using position relative or absolute the result still same.

For Example Please go this link : [Sample](http://www.chandaka.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/sample.jpg)

Comment: I want to recreate. But i forgot jsfiddle domain name..

Comment: similar to what chrome does with its bottom "status" where it holds the link in where it says for example 'Waiting for...' or 'Sending Request to', how when you hover over it it switches to the other side of the screen? is that the effect your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have better luck with javascript. Here is a pretty good looking jQuery Tootip plugin sample that allows you to set the position relative to the element.

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/corner)

Comment: I will try it and i will back again if this not that i mean or even this is what i mean

Comment: Hello
Seems this code will work for me but i don't know how to call the function of this code, please help me out.

I want use at image, when i point my mouse at image then it's will show tooltips, i have a lot image so i need only short code of javascript to call this function with div

Please take a look of this [code][1]


  [1]: http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/effects/multitooltip

Maybe i can make it external javascript file so i can call it at my html file. But i need use short code at my image when mouseover at image.

Answer (score 0):

use data-tooltip attribute with pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`

here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/owupil/611/edit)

Comment: I will try it and i will back again if this not that i mean or even this is what i mean

Comment: This not what i looking for, when i put anchor text of right the tooltip still show outside browser.

Comment: would you please create a demo for your problem